# How to turn off "Require Validation for Converted Leads" for an Apex test?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I'm writing an Apex test class for converted leads.  The key part of the error appears to be the following:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
> 0030t000017YpUfAAK; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,
> Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.: [AccountId]

This is the same error I get when I convert a lead and have the Lead setting "Require Validation for Converted Leads" enabled in my org.  As a result, that setting is off both in production and my current sandbox.

Is there a way to turn that setting off for an Apex test?  "(SeeAllData=true)" does not do this.  The org in question has NPSP (non-Profit Success Pack).

Comment: this setting is org data and hence visible/exploited by all testmethods.

Comment: So tests run with current org settings/data?  Is there a way to query those settings via Apex?  I may be jumping to an unwarranted conclusion, but it's certainly suggestive that I get the same error with an ordinary lead conversion with that setting on as I get in an Apex test (where the setting is ostensibly off.

Comment: so - you want to write/test your lead conversion code in an org where `Require Validation for Converted Leads` could be either checked or unchecked?

Comment: I know that I see a problem with that setting enabled when I do an ordinary lead conversion.  I suspect the error I see with my test code's programmatic lead conversion is due to the setting being on.  Even a way to query the setting value would move me forward.

Comment: but even if you knew the setting, how would that change the logic? the lead conversion gets done one way or another.